# How to modify the existing Excel cell color with python

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

i have a excel about the Work Attendance（Excel to record everyone's working hours）.i need to change the cell because the worker always change their shift.how can change the existing the excel

i used to want to use the `xlwt`,it normally need to set up a new excel.then write.but i need to use the existing excel.

```
def setcellcolor(x,y):
    style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
    pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
    pattern.pattern_fore_colour =4
    style.pattern = pattern
    df.merge(x,x,y,y,style)
```

'Book' object has no attribute 'merge'

Comment: What type is `df`?

Comment: type(df) is  <class 'xlrd.book.Book'>

Comment: df should be <class 'xlwt.Worksheet.Worksheet'>

Comment: You seem to have answered it already. `merge` cant be a method on workbook.

Comment: no ,there are some problems when i use the merge.errer show 'Book' object has no attribute 'merge'

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `xlwt.easyxf` immediately after `style = xlwt.XFStyle()` by skipping the parts including `pattern` variables

```
style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style_bg = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour indigo;'
                       'font: bold 1, name Arial, color-index yellow; align: horiz right')
```

in order to set the style to be used for formatting the cells such as the top-left-most cell to be painted to *indigo*

```
ws.write(0, 0, "abcd", style_bg)
....
wb.save('mydocument123.xls')
```